# Where are free from riba countries?

Tags: riba, banking

In the name of Allah,

I live in a country where all the banks are likely under a central bank that charges interest. So in order to get out of this system, I want to migrate to another country that has free from riba system, or at least there is a room to choose between doing riba or to avoid it at all while at the same time I can still progressing in maintaining my financial status.

So where are the countries that free from riba? And can you explain why they are free from riba? If there is none, can you mention the best country in tackling riba?

May Allah reward us

Answer (score 1):

No where really.

Iran purports to have a 100% shariah compliant financial sector, as does Sudan.

Other than that, the biggest markets for Islamic Banking are places such as Saudi, UAE, Malaysia - but they all have normal interest bearing banks as well. Plus they all have Central Banks that conduct monetary policy via interest rate setting.